# Java Singleton Questions

Tags: java, singleton, abstract-class, generic-programming

I was thinking about making my code a bit cleaner and started to use
the "Singleton Syntax" to access the "main" class of another package...
Like a Modular System.

**Here is my problem:**

I have a package "config" and "console". The main classes of the packages are ConfigModule and ConsoleModule both extending the abstract class Module.
Now I want to write the "getInstance()" Method for the Module class. This is how it would look for one class.

```
private static ConfigModule module;

public static ConfigModule getInstance() {

    if(module == null) {
        module = new ConfigModule();
    }

    return module;
}
```

The problem is I want to make it for the abstract module class... I thought about using generic but thats much confusing with static methods. So thats what I have worked out so far:

```
private static T module; //That wont work.. Do you have an idea?

//To return type: If I call ConfigModule.getInstance().custom an ide cant find the method... my mistake?
public static <T extends Module> T getInstance() {

    if(module == null) {
        module = new T; //Nope... not even close.. but how?
    }

    return (T) module; //Its unchecked.. can I check it?
}
```

I hope you can help me... I googled alot but didnt find a solution.

Comment: So you want one instance for each `T extends Module`? Sounds weird... Also, Singleton is a quite outdated design pattern. Nowadays, you would not implement it yourself but rather use a dependency injection framework.

Comment: Java has no runtime support for generics. Generic type information is lost at during compilation ([type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)), so there is no way to instantiate a generic type. `static T module` wont work either, since generic type parameters belong to the instance, not the class. Long story short, what you are trying to do cannot be easily achieved in Java. IMO, I don't think the time is even worth investing, as I don't see much benefit from a design like this.